# Removing src from a JSON to create an image

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know that this might have been done before, but I cant find the right keywords to search on google for this. Basically what I am trying to do is to create an image element in react from a response object. However the response object contains the html tags so I cant create the image straight forward. Can anyone help me to achieve this. Here is my object property from which I want to display the image

```
{
 "content": "<img src='https://i.cbc.ca/1.5379524.1575076619!/fileImage/httpImage/image.JPG_gen/derivatives/16x9_460/czech-china.JPG' alt='CZECH-CHINA/' width='460' title='Czech Republic&#39;s President Milos Zeman (R) and his Chinese counterpart Xi Jinping walk past an honour guard at Prague Castle in Prague, Czech Republic, March 29, 2016. ' height='259' /> <p>A half-decade ago, China planted an economic flag in Central Europe with its multi-billion-dollar Belt and Road plan to build a vast infrastructure network. Five years on, though, some of those countries are finding the relationship increasingly uncomfortable.</p>"
}
```

How can I decipher this content to get the text as well as the image from here.
As suggested by @Renaldo Balaj I tried using the html to react package but I am still getting a string that is not being rendered in an image or a paragraph. Here is my JSX

```
<div className="dark-overlay">
        <div className="news">
            <Carousel>
            { news.items.map( news => {
                    const htmlInput = news.content;
                    const htmlToReactParser = new HtmlToReactParser();
                    const reactElement = htmlToReactParser.parse(htmlInput);
                    const reactHtml = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(reactElement);
                    console.log(reactHtml);
                    return <Carousel.Item key={news.guid}>
                         {reactHtml}

                    </Carousel.Item>;
                }
            )}
            </Carousel>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to get the src, you can print the img just like you get it from the backend.

There are *packages build for this* thing like: [react-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser)
 (you will just need to give the "`<img >`" , and it will return a fully working img tagg)

*I saw in comments you were having problems implementing it so,* here is the **working demo**: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ncvxgb?file=index.js

Comment: can you explain how can this package will work cause I tried just dumping the content in my JSX but it gets rendered as a string on the webpage not an image, here is what I am doing { news.items.map( news =>

                    <Carousel.Item key={news.guid}>
                        { news.content }</Carousel.Item>

Comment: click in the link there are examples implemented there, it will turn a string into   html tagg , stackoverflow is not a free code service you must do the EASY work by yourself :P  feel free to upvote

Comment: if you have problems after you tried a lot of times, i will help don't worry

Comment: I tried the library, I had to import webpack, however the problem still exists. I am not able to render the image. The library just outputs the whole property as a string with img and p tag

Comment: isn't this a react project ? why you need to import webpack ? is it a react or pure javascript  prooject?

Comment: I guess because of the require keyword, anyways that doesn't matter much since I am able to use the library

Comment: I understand :)    don't worry I got your back, I edited my answer and added a demo in there too  (with your image), feel free to UPVOTE and  mark as accepted answer